# Is it possible to switch back to a previous difficulty?

Tags: path-of-exile

I've just finished the first playthrough and unlocked the [*Cruel* difficulty mode](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Difficulty).  Now I'd like to help a friend who is stuck at the final boss of act 3, *Normal* difficulty.  Is it even possible ?
I can't find how, but it seems weird to me: how can I even trade with a player from another difficulty (without creating a new level 1 caracter) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When selecting a waypoint, you can change the difficulty by selecting an alternate difficulty displayed above the map waypoint list.

[image]

In the picture, the difficult you are on is shown. Once you have completed Normal Difficulty, Cruel Difficulty will appear next to it.